# Entity Framework lookup table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have 3 tables

```
Brands:
BrandID int
BrandName varchar(30)

Products
ProdID int
ProdName varchar(30)

BrandToProd:
BrandID int => FK Brands.BrandID
ProdID int => FK Products.ProdID
```

After generating model from existing database EF omits BrandToProd table and creates Many-To-Many relationships between Brands and Products. I would like to have third entity with following fields:

```
BrandName varchar(30)
ProductsName varchar(30)
```

This will give me possibility to use scaffolding for this entity. Ideally, when I'll add new pair of Brand and Product, EF should check first if such Brand or Product already exist in database (to avoid duplicates), if no, add to corresponding tables and that add mapping to BrandToProd table. If Brand or Product already exist, EF should you existing  BrandID/ProdID value when adding to BrandToProd table. Is there any idea how to do that?

Comment: Some questions: 1) are you using Code First or Database First? 2) If Code First, are you using DataAnnotations such as `[ForeignKey]` or are you using the Fluent API in the context? This is certainly possible to do, but we need to have more information to direct our approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with just adding dummy ID field to my junction table, as I'm frequently changing DB schema (becsuse site development is in progress and I need from time to time update model from database) and don't want to each time remove/add dummy field to database. Another option I've used - SQL View on two tables and stored procedures mapped to corresponding actions (CRUD) in EF

Answer (score 2):

Your `BrandToProd` table is a *pure junction table*, i.e. a table with only two foreign keys. It is an EF feature to model such tables into a many to many association without a class in the conceptual model.

The easiest way to include a pure junction table in the model as an entity class is

- add a dummy field to the database table temporarily
- generate the model
- delete the field from the database
- update the model from the database
- delete the property in the edmx diagram

An alternative way is to edit the edmx manually, but then you really need to know what you're doing. If you don't want to regenerate the model you could generate a second model and investigate the differences in both edmx files by a difference viewer.

However, I wonder if you need to do this. You seem to relate this to duplicate checking. But if you want to add a `Brand` or `Product` to the database you'll have to check for duplicates either way. If you want to add a new association (e.g. adding an existing Brand to Product.Brands) you don't have to check whether it exists. If it does, EF just ignores the "new" association.

Answer (score 1):

As extra point to Gert's answer:
when using surrogate keys, there is always the issue of duplicate management.  Normally there is 1 or more fields that make a logical key.
you can

- a)create a unique index on the Db. Db will complain when the constraint is violated
- b)Execute a logical duplicate check before attempting an insert.

Comment: thanks, thats why I'm decided to leave storage layer do his job and nothing else, now all logic about duplicate checks before insertion new data done at controller level