# Entity Framework turns Pure Junction Look Up Tables into Many to Many relationship

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, entity-framework, orm

I have just recently started working with Entity Framework within an ASP.NET project (which I have also just recently started working with so I'm a little overwhelmed lately)

I have a database that has 4 look up tables. When I added the ADO.Net entity to my asp.net project, I was at first confused as to why my look up tables were gone. After doing some looking, I stumbled upon this :

[Entity Framework lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771501/entity-framework-lookup-table)

and realized that look up tables with no other columns but the foreign keys become many to many relationships. That is all well and good. I might be missing something simple here, which I'm afraid is probably the case, but now I'm lost on how to query for the data that I originally had no problem traversing the look up tables to find.

Here is a generic model of my database (Not the EDM)

Person:
PID

Group:
GID

Requirement:
RID

Action:
AID

Person/Group:
PID
GID

Group/Requirement:
GID
RID

Requirement/Action:
RID
AID

Person/Action:
PID
AID

So now with the many to many relationships between Person, Group, Requirement, and Action
I am unsure how to construct statements within my ASP.Net web form project code to traverse through the relationships like I used to with the look up tables.

I used to be able to query Person/Group where PID = "desired person's id" then use the GID to find all the RID's from Group/Requirement. Then use the RID to find all the AID's from Requirement/Action. Then compare those AID's to all AID's in Person/Action where the AID's matched to check if requirements were fulfilled.

I will not be insulted if you tell me this is something basic in ASP.NET that I've overlooked, but I figured if I asked here and it was answered there would at least be a concise answer for anyone switching from SQL Queries to Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EntityFramework you have the option of adding what is called a '**Navigation Property**'.  For example lets look at these code snippets from a hypothetical Person class.

1 : 1 or 1 : Many from the 1 perspective

```
public class Person
{
  public virtual Group Group {get;set;}
}
```

Many : Many or 1 : Many from the Many perspective

```
public class Person
{
  public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups {get;set;}
}
```

In the case of a many to many relationship, you would use **EntityFramework FluentAPI** to set up the relationships between your Person and Group class.  For 1 to 1 or 1 to Many you can use FluentAPI, **DataAnnotations** or let EntityFramework guess (I believe it guesses PropertyName_ID).

The `virtual` in the property declaration means that I am allowing EntityFramework to **lazy load** the collection when I actually use it, instead of when I am querying the context.  You can declare a navigation property without the virtual keyword, but then you cannot lazy load it.

Hopefully this helps you understand navigating your Entities.  I've bolded some terms that I think you should google to help further understand how EntityFramework operates.

From your question of getting all Actions required by groups for a given person:

```
var requiredActions = myPerson.Groups.SelectMany(x => x.Requirements).SelectMany(x => x.Actions);
```

A persons performed actions would be:

```
var performedActions = myPerson.Actions;
```

Both of these lines assume you've set up the appropriate navigation properties.

Comment: I think the OP is about database first.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get a Person Object you'll have properties for Actions and Groups.

Groups should have a Requirement property as well.

So I think what you're looking for is something like

```
list<int> personIds = {1,2,3};
List<Requirement> requirements = dbContext.Groups.Where(x => x.Person.Count(y => personIds.Contains(y.PersonId) > 0).Select(x => x.Requirements);
List<Action> actions = requirements.Actions;
```

You might be able to get that done is a slicker way, the many-many relation ships where always kind of a pain when I was working in EF too.